# Using findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths to change picture path element- ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

Picture element, in 60 MXD files, disappear and there only blanked rectangle instead.
[image]

I know one way to solved it, by go to the picture properties-->picture tab.

But i try to find a way do it with arcpy. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to change the source of the image. You need to use `ListLayoutElements` on your MXD. From the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayoutelements.htm):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"PICTURE_ELEMENT", "*logo*"):
    if elm.name == "CityLogo":
        elm.sourceImage = r"C:\Project\Data\Photo.bmp"
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project2.mxd")
del mxd
```

Comment: Chad, this code worked only when i delete "*logo*" in the parenthesis- why is it?